# AJAX form submission, solely to prevent page refresh and nothing else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've built a simple HTML/PHP e-mail sign-up form to appear in the footer area of my website. There are only two fields: *email* and *country*.

The form works perfectly for my purposes. Data collection, validation, sanitization, error handling, clear fields, success notification, etc. -- ALL GOOD!

My final step is to implement AJAX to prevent a page refresh. This is all that is required from AJAX.

All tutorials, articles, and answers to related questions on this site I have found offer code that includes functions I've already handled with PHP.

I've gotten as far as the AJAX submission, which works. The page doesn't refresh, user input is inserted to the database, and I receive the confirmation e-mail.

**I would appreciate some guidance (or a link to a tutorial) that can help me implement the PHP error logic and echo PHP success/error messages.**

HTML

```
<form action="process_footer_form/" method="post" id="footer-form">

<ul>

<li>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email"
value="<?php if (isset($email)) {echo $email;} ?>">
</li>

<li>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country"
value="<?php if (isset($country)) {echo $country;} ?>">
</li>

<li>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</li>

</ul>

<?php if (isset($success_message)) {echo $success_message;} ?>
<?php if (isset($error_message)) {echo $error_message;} ?>

</form>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {

    // identify form
    var form = $('#footer-form');

    // create event listener
    $(form).submit(function(event) {

        // disable html submit button
        event.preventDefault();

        // serialize form data
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // submit form using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {

            // 1. echo PHP success message
            // 2. fire PHP clear fields command

        })

        .fail(function(data) {

            // 3. execute PHP error logic here
            // 4. echo PHP error messages

        });  
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

// Load PHPMailer
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

// Create PHPMailer session
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

// SMTP settings
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.xxxxxxxxxx.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' , 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mail->isHTML(true);  

// Sanitize & Validate Input
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$country = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));

// set connection to mysql server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// connect to database
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", $connection);

// insert user input to table
$sql = "INSERT INTO email_subscribers (email,country) VALUES ('$email','$country')";

if (!$connection) {

$error_message = <<<ERROR
<div>ERROR. Form not sent. Please try again or <a href="contact/">contact us</a>.</div>
ERROR;

// Send error notice to host
$mail->Subject = 'Website Error - Footer Form';
$mail->Body = ("Error Notice: A site user is having trouble on the footer form.");
$mail->send();

    } else {

    // run query
    mysql_query($sql, $connection);

$success_message = <<<CONFIRMATION
<div>Subscription complete. Thank you!</div>
CONFIRMATION;

    mysql_close($connection);

    // Send confirmation notice to host.
    $message = <<<HTML
    <span>E-mail: {$email}</span><br>
    <span>Country: {$country}</span>
HTML;

$mail->Subject = 'New E-mail Subscriber - Footer Form';
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->send();

unset($email, $country);
}
} else {

header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/');
exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: Does your code both fire the ajax request *and* refresh the page?

Comment: You are sending the request and not doing anything with the response. Checkout the `done` setting in [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Inside done, you will get the result and you need to modify the current page with it

Comment: There is no page refresh, Alex. The ajax requesting is working, at least partially I guess.

Comment: @mbnyc - If you are not going to use the AJAX callback and use PHP to display the messages, it seems pointless to use AJAX IMO. Might was well just do it with straight PHP.

Comment: @EternalHour - I haven't found a way to submit a form without page refresh using PHP only.

Comment: Well you can't, but my point is that in order to display any output in PHP a page refresh is required anyway.

Comment: @EternalHour, so should I move the field-clearing function, and confirmation and error messaging functions, out of PHP and into this AJAX code? Would this be standard practice? Moving items to the client side makes me feel less secure. I was hoping to keep as much as possible server-side.

Comment: You don't need to move them out of PHP, you would just need to use `json_encode` to send the messages back to AJAX in your success/faliure callback. Then there will be no refresh at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might try simplifying your life by using the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object.  Then your code could look something like this.  I have tested this out.

```
<form method="POST" id="subscription-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="gulliver@tinyletter.com">
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="Lilliput">
<input type="button" value="submit" id="form-submit">
</form>
```

Below this you could put in a div for displaying messages:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Then your jquery/javascript would look something like this:

```
<script>
(function(){
    $("#form-submit").on("click", function(){ submitForm();});
})();


function submitForm(){
var form = document.getElementById("subscription-form");
var fd = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: './PHPscript.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            $("#messages").html(data);
       }
     });
   }
</script>
```

Regarding letting PHP "handle the messages" I think you're missing something about AJAX.

In your initial PHP page you are loading the html that PHP has generated and then PHPs part is finished.  When you make the AJAX call you are asking the server to execute a different PHP script and then return the output of that script back to javascript.

At that point you need to put whatever message PHP has generated back into the current page, which has not and will not reload.  That was the purpose of using AJAX in the first place.  That is what the "messages" div is for.

As a way of completely understanding this create an extremely simple PHPscript.php file that looks like this and try it out:

```
<?php
print $_POST['email'] . ' ' . $_POST['country'];
?>
```

You will see your values returned in the current page inside that messages div.

Comment: Working with your code right now. Haven't gotten it to work yet, but still trying. Also, as I mentioned previously, I have no need to display messages using JQuery or Javascript. All messaging is handled by the PHP. Is there a way to simply send the form with AJAX and just let the PHP handle everything else?

Comment: Sheesh.  I had left off the beginning script tag and the first function.  Just added it in.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks @HeadCode. I'm testing it now. If the php script was on the same page, what would be the "url:" value?

Comment: @mbnyc Don't do that.  You really want to separate your concerns here.  The initial page is for displaying your form and other view stuff.  You want to call a PHP script with your AJAX that is just about processing the request.  You don't want or need any of that html to be processed or output when you are making your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

The first request to, for example `www.mysite.com/something.php` will run the PHP and dump the result into the page.  Ajax doesn't work this way.  You send a `request` to your PHP file, and it sends a `response` that you can then inspect and do something with.

If ajax responses dumped their content into the page like an initial load, mayhem would ensue.

Try something like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

then have a looksie in the console and see what goodness you're getting from the PHP script.  Then build that `.done` callback up to process the results of your request and determine what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first thing, `var that = this` is a trick when you loses context, but where you use it is not somewhere you can lose it .. so forget it :)

Then your `find().each()`, it's a good way of getting your values, but jquery offers a method which is `$( this ).serializeArray()` (it does kinda exactly what your want)

Also, you send your data with ajax, but you have no callback. Your ajax call need to have at least a function to call once everything went fine. This is done with `done()`

Finally, returning `false` does cancel the event in **most** cases but you will prefer `preventDefault()` as it disable default behavior, but still propagate event (for other handlers).

Sum it all:

```
$('form.ajax').submit( function(event) {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serializeArray()
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Ajax call successful");
        console.log("Server answer:" + data);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit: Nvm my first remark, I understood lately your `that = this` stuff.

Comment: Thank you, @cyrbil. However, I may be missing something because your code doesn't work for me. The code I posted will process the form with the PHP, inserting the inputs to the database and sending me an e-mail. It just doesn't execute the tail-end of the script. Your code only fires the alert pop-up "Ajax call successful", but nothing else.

Comment: Look into your browser's console (open with F12) as `console.log("Server answer:" + data);` should have print what the server returned.